# How to delete all NSLog's & comments from my Xcode application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, comments, nslog

Is there anyway to delete the `NSLog` lines from the app by any trick/tool? I usually use `NSLog's` in each and every method to understand the flow of control and to know about the values of the app's variables. I also use lots of comment lines to explain the nature of methods and variables.

At some point these `NSLog`s and comment lines make the program hard to for me to understand. So I need to keep deleting and recreating them. **Is there a way to show/hide them by any trick in Xcode?**

Comment: using replace All in Xcode ????

Comment: How about ignoring the console output?

Answer (score 15):

**Use the global research & replace tool (cmd-shift-f, or Edit, find, Find in Workspace)**

Clic on Find, select Replace
Style => Regular expression

For the `NSLogs`, search

```
NSLog\(.*\).*$
```

and **replace by a space**.

For the `comments,` search

```
\/\/.*$
```

and

```
\/\*.*\*\/
```

and **replace by a space**.

And **finish by replacing manually** those ones

```
/* fjeizghrij
   eopgfjeipgez
*/
```

because I don't know how to grab them safely?

**EDIT :**

At last, **beware of this global replace because you won't be able to undo** ! Copy/paste your project before, for example. You should use the preview fonctionality of the global replace too, and check each entry.

Comment: Close to a down vote....  Using regular expressions to modify code is remarkably fragile.  That'll do the wrong thing if there is, as is common, a sub-expression on the log line.   And it permanently loses the logs.

Comment: Yes, youre right, but it make the job. Maybe I should have talk about the preview fonctionality of global replace.

Comment: ...and upvote for the edit!   Thanks for the clarification.  Global find-and-destroy is very useful, but it is important to know how destructive it is.  Could be useful to cut a release branch, find and destroy all debugging goop, then build for submission!

Comment: Hi just a suggestion do not Replace without checking code i did it once and one guy had boobytrapped the code with if like if(<condition>)
 nslog.It lead to if being applied to next line of code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the exact reason is why you want to remove the `NSLog` lines and comments.

if you can read the source code hard, to remove the comments, **set the comments colour** in the Xcode preferences **to same as the background or set their font size to 1** and you won't see them when you read the code. :)

I have no idea for the `NSLog`, but I'm using the following way to avoid the unwanted logging in the final release.

this is a simple macro:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DebugLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DebugLog(...) { }
#endif
```

I'm using the `DebugLog(...)` as I would use the `NSLog(...)` normally, and **the Xcode is logging only in** `DEBUG` **mode**, I don't need to remove any log when I create the release version of the app.